# Getting root access on meizu x8 (Andriod 8.1.0)

Tags: rooting

I tried various methods that I can found on the web to get root access, but none of them worked. I do not trust the vendor-provided method of getting root access. Does anyone know a way to get root access on meizu x8?

Comment: What all did you try? your question is not clear. Do you know how to manually root? if no have you tried one-tap root apps?

Comment: try to root manually then

Comment: This seems to be the firmware for your device. [meizu X8 Flyme](http://www.flymeos.com/firmwarelist?modelId=125&type=1)

Comment: Can you get the boot.img from the firmware? If yes I will answer an official answer on how to root.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: I take no responsibility on the steps below. Root at your own risk.**

**As per Aayush's comment, I would advice you to read up more on rooting. Make sure you understand the ins and outs and the consequences of rooting, nd the possibility of bricking your device, before you attempt to root.**

1. Install Magisk Manager on your device.
2. Copy the boot.img to your device.
3. Run Magisk Manager.

   1. On the right near Magisk click on Install.
   2. Untick Recovery Mode.
   3. Click on NEXT.
   4. Tick the "Select and Patch a File"
   5. Now select the boot.img file you copied to your device. This will patch the file and save it to you Download folder.
   6. Copy the patched file to your PC.
4. Enable USB debugging and OEM Unlocking in your developer settings.
5. Unlock the bootloader (usually this can be done in fastboot by running `fastboot flashing unlock`. If this doesn't work google "unlock bootloader" with your device name). **This will factory reset your device, you will loose all data.**
6. Flash the patched boot image file in fastboot `fastboot flash boot <path-to-the-patched=image-file>`.
7. Reboot your device `fastboot reboot`.
8. After setting up your device again, install again Magisk Manager on your device. And follow the directions. It will install the Magisk (**Note: it will install Magisk not Magisk Manager which you just installed yourself**) to your device and you should have root).

**GOOD LUCK**

Comment: Sruly, your effort is great!(+1) but i'd recommend Joy Jin not to root his device since he doesn't has proper knowledge and there's a high possibility of him bricking his phone.